# error prevents git fetch with git for windows

Tags: git

```
buttle@puter MINGW64 ~/PhpstormProjects/lolcatz (master)
$ git fetch
git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

I am not executing that command, so why is it preventing my fetch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `git config --global -e`

Remove following config

```
[credential]
    helper = ...
```

Save the file. Then try to fetch again.

Comment: I had `[credential]
        helper = cache --timeout=3600
` in there. I guess that is transformed into an assumed `credential-cache` command? Anyway, this worked!